# Eigen value of inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices

It is known that if a square matrix $A$ with full rank (i.e. invertible matrix) has eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\frac1\lambda$ will be the eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. But can we say if a square matrix $B$ is having eigenvalue $\frac1\lambda$ and another square matrix $A$ of same order as $B$, is having eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $B$ must be the inverse matrix of $A$?

Comment: Consider $I_2$ and $[[1/2, 2/3],[1/2,1/3]]$.

Comment: *The* eigenvalue of a matrix does not exist.

Comment: @itsnotalie For I2 both the eigen values are 1 but in case of the second matrix we get only one eigen value of $A$ as 1. Suppose if $B$ is matrix of order 3 with eigen values $1/lambda1$, $1/lambda2$, $1/lambda3$ and $1/lambda4$ and matrix $A$ of order 3  with eigen values $lambda1$, $lambda2$, $lambda3$ and $lambda4$ then will B be the inverse matrix of A?

Comment: There is also the problem of multiplicity what if $A$ has eigenvalues $1,1,2$ and $B$ has eigenvalues $1,\frac 12,\frac 12$ ?

Comment: @AlolikaRay In general, matrices with identical eigenvalues aren't equal. You can set up an equivalence relation called [similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) which represents all "essentially-identical" matrices in this way.